# ZEND SOAP method must be accessed over SSL

Tags: zend-framework, soap, ssl, https, zend-soap

I have an SSL certificate on my site. It was installed by my hosting provider and I have tested that it was installed properly. I'm trying to consume a SOAP web service from mindbodyonline.com/api and I'm getting this message in the response

> This method must be accessed via SSL (HTTPS).

I'm using Zend Framework's Soap Client and it has been working for most of the services but this particular one contains credit card information and that's probably why it needs the secure connection. I have been unable to find any information on how to send my SOAP request securely. I am creating the client using the code below.

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx?WSDL', array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1));
```

anybody able to help?

Comment: If you create a phpinfo file with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in it, does it show that you have `https` available under `Registered PHP Streams` and/or `ssl/tls` under `Registered Stream Socket Transports`.  I wonder if it is falling back to use http because you don't have openssl built into PHP.

Comment: Yes I see https, ssl and tls there

Comment: Ok, it appears I don't have the SOAP extension installed on my machine, going to add it now and then I can check to see if I get the same error.

Comment: thanks! I've been sifting through google results all day

Comment: Ok got soap set up; when I made a request, it failed but the failure was on the remote server side so I guess I didn't run into the same issue.  Can you post more specific code I can try?  I did: `$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx?WSDL', array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1));
        $client->GetClients();` and the result was `Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException:  at mb.API._0_5.ClientService.GetClients() in \ClientService.asmx.cs:line 837`.  Probably I pass bad data.

Comment: yeah you have to pass in some credentials to get it to work.. Do you have mindbody account? otherwise it won't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12456/discussion-between-devin-crossman-and-drew010)

Comment: I don't have an account.  I just tried the same request using HTTP for the WSDL address and I get the same error so I wonder if the error you are getting was returned by ZF/PHP or by their remote server.  I went into the chat room btw, I'll stick around a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL specifies all endpoints as http not https. So I had to change the endpoint in the Zend_Soap_Client constructor.
The Zend_Soap_Client Docs http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html say that the location option doesn't work in WSDL mode but they're wrong. Adding the location option overrides the endpoint specified in the WSDL. I got it to work using this code

```
$client = new Zend_Soap_Client('https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx?WSDL', array("soap_version"=>SOAP_1_1,'location'=>'https://api.mindbodyonline.com/0_5/ClientService.asmx'));
```

Thanks to drew010 for his help!